# Rotate after crop in react-image-crop library not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

When cropping image in it automatically saves cropped item in state but if click in rotate after that it rotates and saves original not cropped image. If we just crop and save and then open edit to rotate it work as expected.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import ReactCrop from "react-image-crop";
import "react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css";
import CustomCarousel from "../../../../../../shared/molecules/customCarousel";
import Button from "../../../../../../shared/atoms/button";

const EditableFilePreview = ({ file, handleCrop }) => {
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({
    unit: "%",
    width: 50,
    aspect: 1,
  });
  const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
  const [imageRef, setImageRef] = useState(null);
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);

  const isVideo = file.type.startsWith("video/");

  const handleCropChange = (newCrop) => {
    setCrop(newCrop);
  };

  const handleImageLoaded = (image) => {
    setImageRef(image);
  };

  const handleCropComplete = (updatedFile) => {
    if (imageRef && crop.width && crop.height) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const scaleX = imageRef.naturalWidth / imageRef.width;
      const scaleY = imageRef.naturalHeight / imageRef.height;
      canvas.width = crop.width * scaleX;
      canvas.height = crop.height * scaleY;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.drawImage(
        imageRef,
        crop.x * scaleX,
        crop.y * scaleY,
        crop.width * scaleX,
        crop.height * scaleY,
        -canvas.width / 2,
        -canvas.height / 2,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
      );

      const newPreview = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
      setCroppedImage(newPreview);
      handleCrop({
        ...updatedFile,
        preview: newPreview,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleRotate = () => {
    setRotation((prevRotation) => (prevRotation + 90) % 360);
  };

  useEffect(
    (updatedFile) => {
      if (imageRef) {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const { naturalWidth, naturalHeight } = imageRef;
        const maxSize = Math.max(naturalWidth, naturalHeight);

        canvas.width = maxSize;
        canvas.height = maxSize;

        const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        const centerY = canvas.height / 2;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);

        ctx.rotate((rotation * Math.PI) / 180);

        ctx.drawImage(
          imageRef,
          -naturalWidth / 2,
          -naturalHeight / 2,
          naturalWidth,
          naturalHeight
        );

        ctx.restore();

        const newPreview = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
        handleCrop({
          ...updatedFile,
          preview: newPreview,
        });
      }
    },
    [rotation]
  );

  return (
    <div className="file-preview-edit-photo">
      <div className="carousel-image-edit-photo-button-wrapper">
        <Button
          buttonText={"Crop image"}
          buttonStyles="button-primary carousel-edit-image-photo-button text-medium-small"
          onClick={handleCropComplete}
          disabled={isVideo}
        />
        <Button
          buttonText={"Rotate image"}
          buttonStyles="button-primary carousel-edit-image-photo-button text-medium-small"
          onClick={handleRotate}
          disabled={isVideo}
        />
      </div>
      {isVideo ? (
        <video src={file.preview} controls />
      ) : croppedImage ? (
        <img
          src={croppedImage}
          alt={`Preview`}
          style={{ transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`, borderRadius: "12px" }}
        />
      ) : (
        <ReactCrop
          src={file.preview}
          crop={crop}
          onChange={handleCropChange}
          onImageLoaded={handleImageLoaded}
          onComplete={() => {}}
          minHeight={100}
          maxHeight={670}
          minWidth={100}
          maxWidth={670}
          style={{ borderRadius: "12px" }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const EditPhotoCarousel = ({ files, handleOpenEditPhotoModal, setFiles }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(1);

  const handleCarouselChange = (nextSlide) => {
    setCurrentSlide(nextSlide);
  };

  const handleCrop = (croppedImage) => {
    const updatedFiles = [...files];
    updatedFiles[currentSlide - 1].preview = croppedImage.preview;
    setFiles(updatedFiles);
  };

  const carouselList = files.map((file, index) => (
    <EditableFilePreview file={file} key={index} handleCrop={handleCrop} />
  ));

  const responsive = {
    desktop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
      items: 1,
      slidesToSlide: 1,
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
      items: 1,
      slidesToSlide: 1,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="edit-photo-carousel-wrapper">
        <CustomCarousel
          responsive={responsive}
          carouselList={carouselList}
          arrowStyles={"edit-photo-arrow-styles"}
          dotsStyles={"edit-photo-dots-styles"}
          containerStyles={"edit-photo-carousel-container"}
          beforeChange={handleCarouselChange}
        />
        <div className="file-upload-edit-photo-slides text-regular-bold">
          {currentSlide}/{files.length}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditPhotoCarousel;
```

Can anyone see where i am getting wrong
When cropping image in it automatically saves cropped item in state but if click in rotate after that it rotates and saves original not cropped image. If we just crop and save and then open edit to rotate it work as expected.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).